# Openresty log_by_lua_block non blocking http-request

Tags: nginx, curl, lua, openresty

In one of nginx locations I have `log_by_lua_block`, where I need to send several `ngx.var` variables to remote server over http. If I use something like [Lua-cURL](https://github.com/Lua-cURL/Lua-cURLv3) it block nginx worker until the request is completed. What is the correct way to send non blocking http-request from `log_by_lua_block`?

Something like:

```
location / {
   proxy_pass http://host;

   log_by_lua_block {  
          someAsyncCurlRequest(ngx.var)
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did so:

```
location /proxy/ { 
    rewrite /proxy/(.*) /$1  break; 
    allow 127.0.0.1; 
    deny all; 
    proxy_pass $1; 
}

log_by_lua_block {  
    local cjson = require "cjson.safe"
    local postData = {}
    postData["userIP"] = $remote_addr
    res = ngx.location.capture_multi{{"/proxy/http://urlPath",{ method = ngx.HTTP_POST, body = cjson.encode(postData)}},}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the [ngx.locatin.capture](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture).
It will let you

> Issue a synchronous but still non-blocking Nginx Subrequest using uri.

It seems like it may not be possible to do it from log_by_lua_block context. You can try modifying your code to use a different block to perform the operation. For example move the logic to access_by_lua_block to utilize the co-sockets.

Personally I would consider using a different approach to solve the issue, perhaps with a 3rd party tool monitoring the log file and sending the data asynchronously. This is because even performing asynchronous requests may still have a negative effect on nginx.